# how to manage a JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> data structure in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a data file like this:

```
"id"; "a"; "b"; "c"; "d"; "e"; "f"; "outcome"
1144216938;1988;0;0;1;1965.115431348724;19.07168894289186;0
1093965329;2004;1;1;1;302.2244897959184;16.762951334379906;1
....
```

The first column represents the id label for each case, while the last column represents a binary outcome, either 0 or 1. All the variables in-between are used in a logistic regression model (I haven't normalised them yet). I read the file in Spark with:

```
JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile(filename);
JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> parseddata = data
    .map((String line) -> {
        String[] parts = line.split(";");
        double[] points = new double[parts.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < (parts.length - 1); i++) {
            points[i] = Double.valueOf(parts[i]);
        }
        return new LabeledPoint(Double.valueOf(parts[parts.length - 1]), Vectors.dense(points));
    });
```

I am unfamiliar with the LabeledPoint data structure, so this might be easy to solve, but I don't understand how... So I have three related questions:

- how to get rid of the file header? Right now I just eliminate it from the file:

**EDIT**
as per eliasah comment, this should do the trick:

```
    // retrieve the header
    String first = data.first();
    // filter it out
    JavaRDD<String> filteredData = data.filter((String s) -> {
       return !s.contains(first);
    });
```

**END EDIT**

- is there a way to map the first column as row names, so to exclude it from the points used in the regression model - apart from using:

  ```
  for (int i = 1; i < (parts.length - 1); i++) {
      points[i] = Double.valueOf(parts[i]);
  }
  ```
- finally, how to map predictions to the right "id" when I retrieve the predictions from my regression model with:

  ```
  JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Object>> predictionAndLabels = test.map((LabeledPoint p) -> {
     Double prediction = model.predict(p.features());
     return new Tuple2<Object, Object>(prediction, p.label());
  });
  ```

**EDIT 2**
Despite the answer says it all, all I can come up with is:

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Object>> results = filteredData.map((String line) -> {
        String[] parts = line.split(";");
        double[] points = new double[parts.length - 1];
        //skip first column with npi values
        for (int i = 1; i < (parts.length - 1); i++) {
            points[i] = Double.valueOf(parts[i]);
        }
        LabeledPoint labeledPoint = new LabeledPoint(Double.valueOf(parts[parts.length - 1]), Vectors.dense(points));
        return new Tuple2<Object, Object>(parts[0], model.predict(labeledPoint.features()));
    });
```

which is a pity because I am basically redoing the map again... is this the correct way?

**EDIT 3**

Thanks to other comments from eliasah, I now filter data like:

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, LabeledPoint>> parsedData = filteredData.map((String line) -> {
 String[] parts = line.split(";");
 double[] points = new double[parts.length - 1];
 for (int i = 1; i < (parts.length - 1); i++) {
     points[i] = Double.valueOf(parts[i]);
 }
 return new Tuple2<String, LabeledPoint>(parts[0], new LabeledPoint(Double.valueOf(parts[parts.length - 1]), Vectors.dense(points)));
 });
```

I use this for training:

```
JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> training = parsedData
     .map((Tuple2<String, LabeledPoint> z) -> {
         return z._2();
     });
```

And retrieve probabilities for each of my case with:

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Double>> results = parsedData
     .map((Tuple2<String, LabeledPoint> z) -> {
         return new Tuple2<String, Double>(z._1(), model.predict(z._2().features()));
     });
```

Comment: Concerning the header,what I usually with the header is a rdd.first() to fetch the header and then a filter on the rdd.

Comment: As for the points, with Scala I map over the second part and then depending on if is the vector is sparse or dense, i create the vector as so.

Comment: concerning the last question, I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time... say the id=1144216938, after I ran my regression, how to I find the predicted value for that id?

Comment: map over your labeledpoint (label,features) , if label = id, model predict with features

Comment: I thought "label" was supposed to be the dependent variable 0/1... maybe I am missing something...

Comment: yes sorry my bad! (I need a break, working a lot)

Comment: ahaha, thanks anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92772/discussion-between-eliasah-and-simone-gabbriellini).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the header,what I usually with the header is a rdd.first() to fetch the header and then a filter on the rdd :

```
String header = data.first();
JavaRDD<String> filteredData = data.filter((String s) -> {
   return !s.contains(header);
});
```

concerning the last question, with Scala I map over the second part and then depending on if is the vector is sparse or dense, i create the vector as so.

you need to keep track of your id labeledpoint RDD[(Int,LabeledPoint)] (I'm more familiar with scala sorry) then you can mapreduce over this rdd to predict for a labeledpoint.feature

```
rdd.map{ case (id,p) => (id,model.predict(p.features)) }
```

Comment: still I cannot figure out in Java how to keep track of my id labeledpoint... :(

Comment: It should be in your part[0] after you do the split

Comment: It's a way to do it. Not optimal. But correct. The only pity  here is that you are loosing the informations about the labeledpoints created. I'd rather create an RDD of id,labeledpoint then map to compute predictions. You might need to scale of normalize the features vector. You don't want to recompute that again.

Comment: following your lead here... just a last thought: when I have a JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, LabeledPoint>> I cannot pass my data to the model for training, because it expects a RDD<LabeledPoint>...

Comment: You'll need to map your RDD[(String,LabeledPoint)] to RDD[LabeledPoint]. E.g map(_._2) in Scala

Comment: I wonder if this issue (not having an ID for a LabeledPoint) was resolved in Spark by now?

Comment: Which issue are you talking about ? I don't understand what you are referring too

Comment: allowing a LabeledPoint to have an ID or unique index to alleviate the need for stripping the id, passing RDD[LabeledPoint] then recombining with the ID after predicting/etc.

Comment: There is no issue there. It's just useless data to carry around while doing heavy computation.